# Отбрасывание определенного числа разрядов после запятой

Tags: java

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть число (например, 1.2345). Как можно отбросить последнюю цифру в дробной части (без округления), чтобы получилось 1.234? Только я не знаю, сколько цифр после запятой.

Comment: У вас есть число как `double`, или как строка? это важно. Дело в том, что `double` хранит числа как двоичные дроби, и реальное значение вашего double может быть совсем не тем, что вы казалось бы присваиваете (т. к. не все десятичные дроби могут быть выражены точно двоичными дробями).

Гляньте на этот пример: http://ideone.com/23YaVH

Comment: как double

Comment: почитай про класс Math, в нём куча полезных методов. Даже в будущем пригодится под другие задачи

Comment: Тогда задача не очень-то корректна. На самом деле, число `1.2347` внутри содержится как (примерно) `1.2346999999999999086952584548271261155605316162109375` ([пруф](http://ideone.com/dSoWAX)), так что слёту понятие «количество разрядов» расплывается.

Comment: число получается путём ввода, поэтому я не знаю, сколько знаков после запятой введет пользователь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если число вводит пользователь, *не присваивайте его переменной типа `double`*! таким образом вы потеряете информацию о точности числа.

Вместо этого воспользуйтесь типом `BigDecimal`. Вы можете выяснить количество разрядов, считав `scale()`. Для отброса ненужных разрядов воспользуйтесь `setScale(n, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)`.